# Power BI: удаление значения конкретных дат при расчете меры

Tags: powerbi, dax

Прошу помочь составить меру в PBI для расчета значения показателя за предыдущий период, исключая значения 01.01.2022, 02.01.2022 и 01.01.2023 годов

При расчете значения числа чеков за предыдущую неделю использую формулу DAX:

Чеки шт_7дней_тому_назад = CALCULATE('_Меры'[Чеки шт],DATEADD('Дата_view'[Дата],-7,DAY))

Дальше определяю темп прироста чеков:

Чеки прирост = ('_Меры'[Чеки шт]-'_Меры'[Чеки шт_7дней_тому_назад])/'_Меры'[Чеки шт_7дней_тому_назад]

При построении графика темпа прироста чеков происходит визуализация данных, в т.ч. рассчитанных с учетом недели 01.01.2022 (даты 01.01.2022, 02.01.2022) и недели 01.01.2023 (дата 01.01.2023). График нужно построить без этих дат.

В фильтре на странице стоит фильтр: Неделя не является 01.01.2022 и 01.01.2023, необходимый для аналитики по иным показателям, убрать его не могу.
Этот фильтр также не позволяет убрать указанные выше недели из расчета показателей:
Чеки шт_7дней_тому_назад и Чеки прирост.

Прошу помочь разобраться в расчете указанных выше показателей без данных за 01.01.2022,02.01.2022, 01.01.2023.

Возможно ли при расчете меры исключить значения определенных дат? Может быть через конструкции Calculate и Filter (дата не равно такому то значению)?